# Solving $z^n = \omega$ for $z, \omega \in \mathbb{C}$ (Stein and Shakarchi, Ch1 #3)

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem statement:

> With $\omega = se^{i\varphi}$, where $s \ge 0$ and $\varphi \in \mathbb{R}$, solve the
> equation $z^n = \omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$ where $n$ is a natural number. How many solutions are there?

I'm unsure if my approach is sufficient:

- First I write $z = re^{i\theta}$
- I see I need $(re^{i\theta})^n = re^{in\theta} = se^{i\varphi}$
- So this requires $r=s$ and $n\theta = \varphi$ for some natural $n$.
- Therefore if there are any solutions, there are infinitely many due to periodicity.

Alternatively, is the problem saying that since I can pick whatever $z$ I want, I get to dictate $r=s$ and $n\theta = \varphi$ for as many $n$ as I like? And that therefore there are definitely infinitely many solutions?

Am I interpreting the problem incorrectly? What is fixed and what isn't?

Comment: No, there are $n$ solutions for each $\omega$ (including one of multiplicity $n$ in the $\omega=0$ case;

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Complex_roots).

Comment: @Gary, I see. The question asks for some fixed $n$ and $\omega$, how many $z$ exist such that $z$ is an $n$-th root of $\omega$?

Comment: @rootsofunity If you read what I gave you, you will find the answer.

Comment: Your original formula is wrong. Where did $r^n$ disappear to?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta =e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}},$ a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

The solutions are:   $$\omega ^{\frac{1}{n}}\zeta^k,\quad k=0,\dots, n-1,$$

where $\omega ^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt[n]se^{\frac{i\varphi}{n}}.$

---

That there's at most $n$ follows from the factor theorem (or little Bezout), in the Euclidean domain $\Bbb C[x].$